# should we have connected to internet while using android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android studio we write dependencies.

for eg.`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.+'`

is that mean when we want to run or compile project we must connected to internet? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On launch gradle & maven connect to the internet to fetch dependencies from your specified repositories like maven central or jcenter to make sure you have all of your required dependencies.

If you would like to disable this, in Android Studio 0.5.1+ you can enable Offline Mode by navigating to `File->Settings->Gradle->Offline work`. This will stop these dependencies from being fetched and just use the local versions.

[image: Gradle offline option]

**But note** even in offline mode, Gradle will still connect to the internet periodically (every 24 hours) to ensure that dependencies with versions that end in '+' are up to date.